# Show/Hide BottomNavigationView for specific fragment

Tags: java, android, material-design, visibility, bottomnavigationview

In my android application, I want the bottom menu bar to disappear when the user focuses the SearchView (this also pops the soft keyboard up). When the SearchView loses focus, I want to show the bottom navigation bar again.

I have tried using `setVisibility()` and the view does hide or show, but it always retains its height for some reason.Below is the code for my BottomNavigationView:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
    app:elevation="80dp"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
    android:background="?attr/backgroundColor">
```

Code that handles hiding/showing of the navigation bar:

```
// Needed to close the SearchView when pressing back (instead of just losing focus)
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(
    (v, hasFocus) -> {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            adapter.isSearchMode = false;
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            adapter.isSearchMode = true;
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

The BottomNavigationView is held by a LinearLayout like so:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_top_shadow"/>

                <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
                    app:elevation="80dp"
                    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
                    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
                    android:background="?attr/backgroundColor">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:weightSum="5"
                        android:elevation="16dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center|top">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/missed_calls"
                                style="@style/unread_count_font"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/unread_message_count_bg"
                                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:visibility="gone"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center|top">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/missed_chats"
                                style="@style/unread_count_font"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/unread_message_count_bg"
                                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:visibility="gone"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>


            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your BottomNavigation use this code snippet:

`setVisibility(View.GONE)`

View.Gone = No Space lefts for view.

Comment: Yea this is the code I'm showing to hide the navigation bar, but the height is still retained.

Comment: Provide your layout which holds BottomNavigationView.

Comment: @George make LinearLayout and BottomNavigationView height both warp_content. Your layout design is messy. we usually use CoordinatorLayout for BottomnavigationView.

Comment: many thanks, hardcoding the height for both views was the issue! I had tried switching to CoordinatorLayout, which didn't work either. I've accepted the answer since your comment solved it for me. Also, I know, I'm amending existing code and need to be more efficient!